# jquery ajax and call a script function

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown onchane function in my javascript. I wish to call an asyn process that will call a funstion in another javascript.  whilst that is bring processed I want to show an in-progress image.  There is a lot of functionality happenening as the user does a selection in the drop down. I wrote the following code but the function in the script is called prior to the before send and thus the progress image is not displaying

```
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: GetUserDetails(), //note this is a function in a seperate javascript
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: isVal }),
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('[id$=divAjaxLoader]').show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('[id$=divAjaxLoader]').hide(); },
            success: function(response) {
                if ( /\bFailed\b/.test(response.d) == false) {
                   //details...
                    }
            }
        }
```

in my masterpage i load the scripts and one of those scripts has the function GetUserDetails().  That is a long running process....

However the url is executed before the beforesend and thus the inprogress never shows..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userDetailsUrl = GetUserDetails();

$.ajax({
   url: userDetailsUrl,
   ...
})
```

I think this should work.